# precision errors with numpy

Tags: numpy, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

Can someone explain this:

```
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 11)
array([0.01074219])
>>> 22.0 / (2 ** 11)
0.0107421875
>>>
```

Numpy seems to generates an erroneous result, probably some kind of precision error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The last non-zero digit to the right of the decimal point for non whole number floats is always 5.  I find this factoid (not sure where it is written; i sort of postulated it myself) useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(precision=15)
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 11)
array([0.0107421875])
```

fixes this