# Is there a way to force numpy.set_printoptions to show the exact float value?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Following [question 59674518](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674518/precision-errors-with-numpy), is there a way for numpy.set_printoptions to ensure the EXACT float value is displayed, without displaying trailing zeros, and without knowing the value a priori?  I have tried all 4 float mode options to no avail.  Just trying to understand; no ultimate objective.  (I think it can't be done, if so, what is the rational?  Just a feature not in existence [yet]?).

```
Mac_3.2.57$python3
Python 3.7.1 (default, Nov  6 2018, 18:45:35) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(precision=15)
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 11)
array([0.0107421875])
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 26)
array([3.278255462646484e-07])
>>> print("%.45f" % (numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 26)).item(0))
0.000000327825546264648437500000000000000000000
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(floatmode="fixed")
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 26)
array([3.278255462646484e-07])
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(floatmode="unique")
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 26)
array([3.2782554626464844e-07])
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(floatmode="maxprec")
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 26)
array([3.278255462646484e-07])
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(floatmode="maxprec_equal")
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 26)
array([3.278255462646484e-07])
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(precision=45,floatmode="fixed")
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 26)
array([3.278255462646484375000000000000000000000000000e-07])
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(precision=45,floatmode="unique")
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 26)
array([3.2782554626464844e-07])
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(precision=45,floatmode="maxprec")
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 26)
array([3.2782554626464844e-07])
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(precision=45,floatmode="maxprec_equal")
>>> numpy.array([22.0], dtype=numpy.float64) / (2 ** 26)
array([3.2782554626464844e-07])
>>>
```

Comment: Are you aware that printing some values exactly requires many hundreds of digits? The exact value of `4.4501477170144023e-308` takes 1076 characters when printed in decimal in fixed-point format (and 773 characters if printed in scientific format). Sadly, this comment box is too small to contain it.

Comment: @ Mark Dickinson  Yes, I am aware of the many hundreds of possible digits.

Comment: @ Mark Dickinson BTW, 4.4501477170144023e-308 is an inexact representation of a subnormal number.  But I get your point.  Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Ah sorry and thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: @Andrew: Inexact, yes, but it's normal, not subnormal. Making the (pretty darn safe) assumption that the IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point format is in use, the closest exactly representable float to `4.4501477170144023e-308` (probably best expressed in hexadecimal form as `0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022`) is almost twice the value of the smallest normal (`0x1.0000000000000p-1022`).

Comment: Sorry, Mark.  I stand corrected. :-)

Comment: found it in c here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212490/function-to-print-a-double-exactly

Comment: FWIW, without the NumPy aspect, my go-to for this in Python is to convert to `Decimal` and then to `str`: e.g., `str(Decimal(0.1))` -> `'0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625'`. This also works for `np.float64` instances (but not `np.float32`: those need to be converted to `float` first). But that doesn't help with the `set_printoptions` question - I think the answer there is simply "no".

Comment: @Mark Dickinson  Thanks; makes sense.  Using set_printoptions was not the main objective, no even a requirement. :-)